# infinite loop in a rake task iterating over an ActiveSupport date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, activesupport

I'm having a problem with my rake task hanging in an infinite loop. So far, I've been able to isolate the problem to a piece of code converting a date range to an array. Even if I directly invoke this:

```
(1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month).to_a.each {|d| p d}
```

the task hangs iterating over the same elements forever:

```
"2012-06-01 00:40:41 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:41 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:41 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:41 UTC"
"2012-05-31 20:40:41 UTC"
"2012-05-31 20:40:41 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:42 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:42 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:42 UTC"
"2012-06-01 00:40:42 UTC"
"2012-05-31 20:40:42 UTC"
"2012-05-31 20:40:42 UTC"
...
```

If instead I use this

```
(Date.new(2012,6,1)..Date.new(2012,6,30)).to_a.each {|d| p d}
```

everything works, so it has to be something with using ActiveSupport extensions for Date/Time specifically. Has anyone else seen this?

This happens in development environment on a Windows box with Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.3, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `Time` range for a month with 1 second increments and ~2.5 million entries:

```
(1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)
# => Fri, 01 Jun 2012 00:00:00 CEST +02:00..Sat, 30 Jun 2012 23:59:59 CEST +02:00
1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.succ
# => Fri, 01 Jun 2012 00:00:01 CEST +02:00
```

To create a `Date` range use:

```
(1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date..1.month.ago.end_of_month.to_date)
# => Fri, 01 Jun 2012..Sat, 30 Jun 2012
1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date.succ
# => Sat, 02 Jun 2012
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just figured out that what I was taking for an infinite loop was actually a loop iterating over every second in a month... Converting boundaries from `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` to `Dates` works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_date` to convert `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` to `Date`.

```
(1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_date..1.month.ago.end_of_month.to_date).
  each do |day| 
    p day
  end
```

This will iterate over days in a past month.

It appears that the problem lays in using `succ` method on `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` which is raising `Time#succ is obsolete` warnings.

Comment: It's not really the warnings (for some reason I only see them if I run this code in rails console, not from rake) but the loop with a bazillion iterations that is the culprit, as Stefan pointed out. +1 for an acceptable solution anyway.